# iOS: Redraw parent view after Popover is dismissed

Tags: ios

I have a parent view controller and another view controller for a popover. The popover is correctly dismissed. Pressing a button on the parent view controller will spawn the popover as intended. There is a button in the popover view that, when pressed, should change the color of the button on the parent view.

The issue I am having is that when I press the button in the popover, it dismisses, but the button in the parent view controller does not change.

I have tried `[self.view setNeedsDisplay]` in the parent view controller. I have tried calling this in the popover delegate method AND the `- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController` method. The latter method is never called. The former method is called, but it does not redraw the view inside the parent view controller.

I attempted to add a delay to the redraw using `performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:` with no luck at all.

I tried to redraw JUST the button object itself which didn't work. I also called `removeFromSuperview` before calling `setNeedsDisplay` with no luck.

Based on the research I have done, I feel that it is necessary to state that I am not doing any sort of multi-threading with this app. Also, this small app is built with Storyboard.

Comment: Is the outer controller dismissing the popover?

Comment: Yes, the parent view controller calls the delegate method that dismisses the popover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making a simple mistake when using `setNeedsDisplay`. After reading the documentation, I realized that `setNeedsDisplay` will re-draw if there is some content change. I was not changing the content correctly so it did not trigger a change.

I changed the color of the button during the delegate method that also closed the popover. After the color change I called `setNeedsDisplay`. This worked out nicely.